# What is this SQL Server OUTPUT clause effect in SSIS package step?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am editing this question because I was not clear enough.

I started maintaining an SSIS package, and I haven't worked on SQL Server for years, and I see this code and don't know how SSIS is dealing with it:

There is a table called "employees", and we are running this query:

```
UPDATE t SET IsProcessed = 1 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.RecordId, INSERTED.SiteId, INSERTED.EmployeeId, INSERTED.FirstName, INSERTED.MiddleName, 
        INSERTED.LastName, INSERTED.IsProcessed
    FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[employees] AS t
    WHERE IsProcessed = 0
```

So, does SSIS only shows the output of the command, or it takes that output as an input to the next step?

Can you help please?

Comment: [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Btw, you have enough rep to know you should google first.

Comment: I was not clear in my question, because I wrote it very fast. 
What I wanted to know is, if the SSIS takes the "output" and consider it an input for the next SSIS step in the package

Comment: much better. But you could still easily test it yourself. Otherwise you'd best delete this question and ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This will list all the row values that were updated. The after (the new updated value) columns are listed. If the user wanted the previous values they could have listed deleted.column-name. This is a form of auditing the changes.